# Jsp page java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm an intern in Java development and I'm stuck with a problem on my jsp page when I run my

project I got this exception :

GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" for the servlet LinkedServlet has generated an exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet

here is the code of my jsp :

```
<%@page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<html>
<body>
    <p>
        <c:forEach var="cate" items="${defaultResult}">
      ${cate}
     </c:forEach>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any idea to solve this problem it would be very helpful.

Thank in advance

Cyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the `servlet.jar` or `javaee.jar` is not in your CLASSPATH.  What servlet/JSP engine are you deploying and running with?  Find the JAR in your container that has javax.servlet.Servlet in it.  Make sure your class loader can see it, too.

Comment: Thank's for responding so quickly, I'm using Tomcat 6 and I see  the servlet-api.jar library in my Libraries under Apache Tomcat v6.0, is it the same as servlet.jar

Comment: Ok now I have my classpath configure in my manifest and I still have the same error, is there anything else to do ?

Comment: I forgot to add the javaee.jar that you were talking about. Now it works thank you very much